# json-rules-engine processing array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, rule-engine

Any help would be appreciated !! I couldn't find an answer.

Given input facts to the engine such as -

```
const facts = {
  cart: {
    prop1: true,
    prop2: "My Cart",
    prop3: {
      prop4: "North America"
    },
    products: [
      {
        category: 1,
        classification: null
      },
      {
        category: 2,
        classification: null
      },
      {
        category: 1,
        classification: null
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I want to be able to process each object in the products array and define a separate rule for each category and set the classification field for that category.

Something like -

```
let condition1 = {
  all: [
    {
      fact: 'category',
      operator: 'equal',
      value: 1
    }
  ]
};

let condition2 = {
  all: [
    {
      fact: 'category',
      operator: 'equal',
      value: 2
    }
  ]
};

let event1 = {
  type: 'category 1 event'
  // Update classification
};

let event2 = {
  type: 'category 2 event'
  // Update classification
};
```

How do I do this? Do i set the classification field in the event handler for that event? How do I access the object the category belongs to?

I tried using the below, but it selects all the category values from each object. I want to be able to process each object separately.

```
let condition = {
  all: [
    {
      fact: 'cart',
      operator: 'contains',
      value: 1,
      path: '$.products[*].category'
    }
  ]
}
```

I cant add them as runTime facts either since you can have only 1 runtime fact and its value. (No Duplicates)